# Name (Year) Title Bibliography Style (CSL)

Tags: citing, csl

For a specific use case, I would like to show citations in-line in the text with the style: `Authors (Year) Title` and nothing else. So for example I want to get the following citation style:

> Gu et al. (2017) Non-Autoregressive Neural Machine Translation

from the bibtex entry in my bibliography shown below.

Is there a Citation Style Language style that allows me to do exactly this? Is this available for example in [github.com/citation-style-language/styles/](https://github.com/citation-style-language/styles/)?

---

```
@misc{https://doi.org/10.48550/arxiv.1711.02281,
  doi       = {10.48550/ARXIV.1711.02281},
  url       = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02281},
  author    = {Gu, Jiatao and Bradbury, James and Xiong, Caiming and Li, Victor O. K. and Socher, Richard},
  keywords  = {Computation and Language (cs.CL), Machine Learning (cs.LG), FOS: Computer and information sciences, FOS: Computer and information sciences},
  title     = {Non-Autoregressive Neural Machine Translation},
  publisher = {arXiv},
  year      = {2017},
  copyright = {arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license}
}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE.

Comment: As far as I know, the current implementation of CSL does not support the distinction between parenthetic and non-parenthetic citations such as “(author, year)” vs. “author (year)”. This is supposed to be added in the upcoming update to the standard.

Answer (score 1):

An emulation of a CSL can be done using expl3's regex capacity, such that an instruction such as `space` is converted to the Biblatex command `\addspace`, `title` is converted to `\printfield{title}`, and so on.

The markdown-type CSL can be stored in various places.

In this example, the instructions are passed to the regex via the prenote field of a dedicated citation command `\cslcite` (so that different formats are possible using the same citation command, just different prenote settings):

[image: Gu as CSL]

The citation looks like this:

```
\cslcite[given-family, name, space, lparen, year, rparen, space, title][]{gu}
```

The method can be worked up to a full package, using any `A->B` translation technique, not just the rudimentary markdown for the `A` component as used here.

MWE

```
% arara: lualatex
% arara: biber
% arara: lualatex


\begin{filecontents*}[overwrite]{\jobname.bib}
@misc{gu,
  doi       = {10.48550/ARXIV.1711.02281},
  url       = {https://arxiv.org/abs/1711.02281},
  author    = {Gu, Jiatao and Bradbury, James and Xiong, Caiming and Li, Victor O. K. and Socher, Richard},
  keywords  = {Computation and Language (cs.CL), Machine Learning (cs.LG), FOS: Computer and information sciences, FOS: Computer and information sciences},
  title     = {Non-Autoregressive Neural Machine Translation},
  publisher = {arXiv},
  year      = {2017},
  copyright = {arXiv.org perpetual, non-exclusive license}
}

@Book{1990,
  title     = {title},
  publisher = {publisher},
  date      = {1990},
  author    = {author},
  urldate={2022-11-28},
  url={zzz.zzz},
}


\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{FreeSerif}    

\usepackage[style=authoryear]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}




\ExplSyntaxOn

\tl_new:N \l_myscriptname_tl
\NewDocumentCommand { \getblcommand } { m }
{
\tl_set:Nx \l_myscriptname_tl { #1 }
%\tl_show:N \l_myscriptname_tl 

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ given\-family } 
{ 
\c{DeclareNameAlias}
\cB\{ author\cE\}
\cB\{ given-family \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl


%formatting
\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ itcolon } 
{ 
\c{textit} \cB\{ \c{addcolon} \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ isubtitle } 
{ 
isubxxx
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl


\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ subtitle } 
{ 
subxxx
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ emdash } 
{ 
\c{addspace}---\c{addspace}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ endash } 
{ 
\c{addspace}--\c{addspace}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ dot } 
{ 
\c{adddot}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ comma } 
{ 
\c{addcomma}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ colon } 
{ 
\c{addcolon}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ space } 
{ 
\c{addspace}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ lparen } 
{ 
(
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ rparen } 
{ 
)
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ lbrace } 
{ 
\{
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ rbrace } 
{ 
\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ name } 
{ 
\c{printnames} \cB\{ author \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ title } 
{ 
\c{printfield} \cB\{ title \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ edition } 
{ 
\c{printfield} \cB\{ edition \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ location } 
{ 
\c{printlist} \cB\{ location \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ publisher } 
{ 
\c{printlist} \cB\{ publisher \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ year } 
{ 
\c{thefield} \cB\{ year \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ volume } 
{ 
\c{printfield} \cB\{ volume \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ note } 
{ 
\c{thefield} \cB\{ note \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl


\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ isubxxx } 
{ 
\c{printfield} [emph] \cB\{ subtitle \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl

\regex_replace_all:nnN 
{ subxxx } 
{ 
\c{printfield} \cB\{ subtitle \cE\}
} 
\l_myscriptname_tl


%\tl_show:N \l_myscriptname_tl 

%output

\tl_use:N \l_myscriptname_tl
}


\ExplSyntaxOff


\DeclareCiteCommand{\cslcite}%
{}%
{%
\forcsvfield{\getblcommand}{prenote}%
}%
{%
%\multicitedelim%
}%
{\usebibmacro{postnote}%
 }




\begin{document}
Normal cite: \cite{gu}.

Inline, using prenote to hold a custom CSV list: \cslcite[given-family, name, space, lparen, year, rparen, space, title][]{gu}.

\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

Using Biblatex's numeric style option, `[style=numeric]`, the output looks like this:

[image: Gu 2]

Answer (score 0):

There is a web page https://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/ for searching CSL style by unfortunately I can't find a style in the given "author (date) title" format.

[image]

I suggest modifying an existing style. For example, you can modify the citation layout in APA.csl

```xml
    <layout prefix="(" suffix=")" delimiter="; ">
      <group delimiter=", ">
        <text macro="author-intext"/>
        <text macro="date-intext"/>
        <text macro="citation-locator"/>
      </group>
    </layout>
```

to

```xml
    <layout delimiter="; ">
      <group delimiter=" ">
        <text macro="author-intext"/>
        <text macro="date-intext" prefix="(" suffix=")"/>
        <text variable="title" form="short"/>
        <text macro="citation-locator"/>
      </group>
    </layout>
```

Then it produces the expected output.

[image]